# can we call a class attribute in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

By using jquery, i want to display one ovwelay window after clicking the input field. And that window must have two input fields.

Comment: [What have your tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What are you even trying to do..? Could you explain, clearly, what HTML you've got, what the user interaction is, and what result you expect? Then we'll at least understand the question, which is a start.

Comment: the overlay window is coming by default, by i want that window has to come when ever i clicked the input field. For that what i need to do?

Comment: the page has one input field, when ever i clicked tha input field one overlay window has to come with another input field.

Comment: try to learn jQuery the http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: "the overlay window is coming by default" I guess right out of Nirvana…

Comment: You *really* need to show us your HTML and your JavaScript/jQuery (even if it's not working, show what you've tried). link us to a demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), or similar. Please: help *us* to help *you*.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").click(function(){
 $("div").show("<input type="text" name="address">");
    $("div").css({"background-color":"yellow","font-size":"200%","left":"200", "right":"200", "top":"200" ,"bottom":"200"});
  });
});</script>
</head>

<body>
by text: <input type="text" name="by_text" rel="div.overlay:eq(0)" >
<div>
//what i need to do here?
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: is it works? is it the right way or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the page has one input field, when ever i clicked tha input field one overlay window has to come with another input field.

```
<input onclick='prompt("Another input","...");' />
```